# Reload logstash config files even the file hasn't changed

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using logstash to put messages to AWS Kinesis stream and the output plugin requires authentication, this authentication will be refer to environment variable or from a file. We don't have to set the user and access key in the logstash config, by default it will refer to the env variable or a file. Now this credential will change and i have to reload the logstash pipeline. With hot reload or auto reload I think the logstash will look for any change in the config but in my case the logstash config will not change, the environment variable or the file will change. How can we force the logstash to reload the config file in this case.

```
# Sample Logstash configuration for creating a simple
# Beats -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.

input {
   file {
    path => "\xx\\elk.log"
  }
}

output {
 kinesis {
    stream_name => "acars-stream"
    region => "us-east-2"
  }
}
```

The plugin used - https://github.com/samcday/logstash-output-kinesis

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that credentials may be passed using environment variables, then you can use environment variables in output plugin with auto reload of config enabled for logstash. Something along these lines:

```
output {
 kinesis {
    stream_name => "acars-stream"
    region => "us-east-2"
    access_key => "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
    secret_key => "${AWS_SECRET_KEY}"    
  }
}
```

If that is not the option then you can extend the process which updates the credentials file, when they credentials need to be updated, to also reload Logstash config.

Refer to reload docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.4/reloading-config.html
You would do something like:

```
kill -1 PID_OF_YOUR_LOGSTASH_PROCESS
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I will go with the second option, can you please let me know how to reload the Logstash config without stopping and starting the logstash

Comment: @Developer i have added link to reload config docs from logstash to the answer, for your reference.

Comment: Thanks @Furhan S. I have another concern since the pipeline is not changing so the logstash is not reloading the pipeline. I can achieve this by restarting logstash. Can we force logstash to reload config even if the config changes are not visible as per the Kinesis plugin it will look for a credential file in a directory

Comment: @Developer its pretty late for followup but just wondering if you were able to resolve this. What happened when you forcefully reload config (kill -1 $PID) even if the config didn't change?